# How can I fit a distribution to a dataset while forcing it through an exact point in r?

Tags: r, distributions, gamma-distribution, weibull-distribution, constraint

This code was kindly recommended to me in my original question.  It returned the same parameter estimates as the software called CRAFT by Aon Benfield.  I have also managed to replicate it for the Weibull distribution.
I was wondering if anyone could help me replicate if for Pareto?  Based on CRAFT, I would expect a shape of ~0.59 and scale of ~55.15 (b~93 and q~1.7).  Finally, I would also like to do the same but using the SSQ method instead of MLE?

```
My data = c(28.744, 385.714, 20.595, 99.350,31.864, 77.713, 264.408, 21.204, 31.937, 0.900, 18.762, 173.276, 23.707)
```

````
constrained_mle <- function(x, p, q) {
  lnL <- function(shape) {
    # Solving q = qgamma(p, shape)*scale for the necssary scale
    scale <- q/qgamma(p, shape)
    sum(dgamma(x, shape, scale=scale, log=TRUE))
  }
  res <- optimise(lnL, lower=0, upper=1e+3, maximum=TRUE, tol=1e-8)
  scale <- q/qgamma(p, res$maximum)
  c(scale=scale, shape=res$maximum)
}
par <- constrained_mle(x, .95, 500.912)
par
#>       scale       shape 
#> 231.0561574   0.6038756
# checking that the solution is correct
qgamma(.95, scale=par[1], shape=par[2])
#> [1] 500.912 ```
````

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: So I have a data set: loss <- c(28.744,385.714,20.595,99.350,31.864,77.713,264.408,21.204,31.937,0.900,18.762,173.276,23.707).  I know I can fit a gamma curve to this by using fitdist(loss,distr="gamma",method="mle").  However, I would also like the fitted curve to be forced through the value of 500.612 at a percentile of 95.646%.  I would then like to obtain the parameters/view the plot of this adjusted gamma fit.

Comment: Hi Tom, please add any relevant information by editing your post. Comments in the future may get removed or may be overlooked.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Tom. That might not be a great way to shape the tail.  But if you're sure that's what you want to do, then you likely are adept enough with whatever your fitting method might be to frame it as an optimization problem and solve it subject to this constraint.  Evidently there are plenty of details lurking here that you need to spell out before we can provide any specific help: in particular, what method you are using and what distribution family specifically you want to fit.  Please, then, edit your post to supply adequate information about your problem.

Comment: I have added some more relevant information to the post

Comment: Could you explain how you know $500.612$ is the 95th percentile?  If this is an empirical datum then you can use a straightforward maximum likelihood estimator but if it's somehow a hard constraint, such as predicted by a scientific theory, then you need a different method.

Comment: This constraint is calculated separately.  The data is effectively loss data for given hurricanes.  We treat that value as a hard constraint.  We currently fit the graph using a system produced by AON called CRAFT.  In this we tend to allow for a variation in the percentile of 0.01%

Comment: For some distributions there might be a parametization that keeps some quantile fixed. What distribution are you thinking of?

Answer (score 5):

You can fit a gamma distribution in R with *optim*, e.g. by minimizing the sum of squared errors for the mean and the 95th percentile, which actually sets both errors to zero:

```
obs = c(28.744,385.714,20.595,99.350,31.864,77.713,       
264.408,21.204,31.937,0.900,18.762,173.276,23.707)
tail = 500.912

error = function(x)(qgamma(0.95, shape=x[1], scale=x[2]) - tail)^2 + (x[1]*x[2]-mean(obs))^2

params = optim(c(1,1), error)$par
params
```

[The code](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=obs%20%3D%20c(28.744%2C385.714%2C20.595%2C99.350%2C31.864%2C77.713%2C264.408%2C21.204%2C31.937%2C0.900%2C18.762%2C173.276%2C23.707)%0Atail%20%3D%20500.912%0A%0Aerror%20%3D%20function(x)(qgamma(0.95%2C%20shape%3Dx%5B1%5D%2C%20scale%3Dx%5B2%5D)%20-%20tail)%5E2%20%2B%20(x%5B1%5D*x%5B2%5D-mean(obs))%5E2%0A%0Aoptim(c(1%2C1)%2C%20error)) uses the formula for the gamma’s mean and gets the desired mean and percentile exactly with a shape parameter of 0.147 and a scale parameter of 616.6.

You can then check the quantile with

```
qgamma(0.95, shape=params[1], scale=params[2])
```

You can also check the log-likelihood of the result with

```
sum(log(dgamma(shape = params[1], scale = params[2], obs)))
```

and compare it with the log-likelihood from other two-parameter distributions.

Comment: Thanks for this Matt.  If you were then to check if this has worked by labelling the optim and using qgamma, it does not return 500 for the 95th percentile?

Comment: I get 500.8 from qgamma(0.95, shape=0.147, scale=616.6)

Comment: @Tom Increasing the penalty/cost for the difference in the tail can get the 95th percentile closer. Alternatively you could place a fixed boundary although that might make the optimization algorithm run badly

Comment: Thanks Matt, I can now see that.  I want to do the same with a weibull distribution.  How could I then compare the two with regards to their fit to the original data?

Comment: Since the Weibull and Gamma distributions both have two parameters, the usual approach would be comparing the log-likelihood functions (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function). Eg the log-likelihood for the above example is *sum(log(dgamma(shape = 0.147, scale = 616.6, obs)))*

Comment: Why would this loss function make sense?  Combining squared errors of the sample mean in equal measure with a squared deviation from the quantile looks arbitrary.  What statistical properties would this procedure have?  It *looks* like a modified MM estimator that matches the first moment while meeting the constraint, so there's a start.  But have you checked the goodness of fit?  (It's not very good, because the range of the percentiles of the data is only 0.52, which is unusually short.) One might begin by testing the hypothesis that the 95th percentile is the claimed one.

Comment: @whuber, I’m just using that function to solve two equations simultaneously, so weighting the errors would not affect the answer. (Meanwhile, the lack of fit is an issue with the question, but I think it deserves an answer anyway.)

Comment: I see -- so why not describe your solution exactly that way, since the use of the loss function is merely a computational tool?  Indeed, since the mean of any Gamma function is a simple function of its shape and scale parameters, why even do the computation with two parameters?  Just use one parameter and adjust it to match the percentile.  That's a simple and *much* more efficient root-finding problem.

Comment: @whuber, I’ve updated my answer to reflect the discussion in these comments with you and the OP — as moderator will you delete the comments that are not needed now?

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Because there are still several ideas in the comments not reflected in that, I am reluctant to delete them.  These ideas include (1) the lack of a good fit and (2) a better method of estimating the parameters using your MM approach.

Answer (score 4):

For distribution with a scale parameter such as the gamma and the weibull, the likelihood can be maximised numerically with respect to the remaining parameters (the shape in case of the gamma and the weibull) since for any given value of those parameters (the shape), there will be only a single value of the scale parameter for which the 95% quantile of the distribution matches the target value.  The following R code implements this method:

```r
x <- c(28.744,385.714,20.595,99.350,31.864,77.713,       
  264.408,21.204,31.937,0.900,18.762,173.276,23.707)
constrained_mle <- function(x, p, q) {
  lnL <- function(shape) {
    # Solving q = qgamma(p, shape)*scale for the necssary scale
    scale <- q/qgamma(p, shape)
    sum(dgamma(x, shape, scale=scale, log=TRUE))
  }
  res <- optimise(lnL, lower=0, upper=1e+3, maximum=TRUE, tol=1e-8)
  scale <- q/qgamma(p, res$maximum)
  c(scale=scale, shape=res$maximum)
}
par <- constrained_mle(x, .95, 500.912)
par
#>       scale       shape 
#> 231.0561574   0.6038756
# checking that the solution is correct
qgamma(.95, scale=par[1], shape=par[2])
#> [1] 500.912
```

The constained MLEs are evidently quite different from the estimates produced by matching the first moment and the target quantile (shape=0.1470374 and scale=616.5818235) in the answer by Matt F.

Comment: Hi Jarle, this is brilliant thank you.  So I assume the same function could apply to Weibull, and what about Pareto2?

Comment: @Tom Yes, sure.  But note that for the Pareto, the constained likelihood may be zero for some values of the shape parameter since the support is of the pdf is $[x_m,\infty)$, that is, it depends on the scale parameter $x_m$.

Comment: When trying the function for Weibull, I receive this error:                                                                                        
 Warning messages:
1: In optimise(lnL, lower = 0, upper = 1000, maximum = TRUE,  ... :
  NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value.                                                                   When trying it with pareto, i receive this error:                                                         
Error in qpareto(p, shape) : argument "shape" is missing, with no default.  Sorry for the basic questions, I am a beginner in r!

Comment: I have managed to replicate it for Weibull but I am still struggling with pareto?

Comment: Also, is there an alternative function that I could use for the SSQ method?

Comment: For the Pareto you probably have to restrict the `upper` and `lower` arguments in the call to `optimise` to more sensible values. The constraint that the scale $x_m$ needs to be no larger than the smallest observation, this translates to a restriction also on the shape parameter.

Comment: @Tom For the "SSQ" method in the other answer, this is really just a system of two equations in two unknowns (the shape and the scale) but since you can solve the first equation for the scale given the shape, you can reduce this to a single equation that can be solved numerically using e.g. `uniroot` as suggested by @whuber.

Comment: When I run it on Aon Benfield CRAFT, I get b = 92.74, q = 1.68.  Based on this, I would have thought using a lower and upper argument of 0.01 and 100 should work but it does not?  Perhaps the function needs editing as well